# Kotlin approach to perform an operation after any of condition blocks are executed

Tags: kotlin

Getting to know Kotlin!

```
var flag = false;
if(condition) {
    //do one thing
    flag = true;
}
if(condition2) {
    //do another thing
    flag = true;
}
if(flag)
    save();
```

What is the right way to do this in Kotlin avoiding the `flag` approach?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "the flag approach". What do you not like about it?

Comment: What would be in this condition? Would it be based on a single variable?

Comment: @JoãoDias, the conditions are complex.

Comment: I don't think there's any cleaner way than how you have done it with the flag.

Comment: Is it meant to short-circuit after a condition is met? So if ``condition`` is true, it does ``one thing`` and then skips the ``condition2`` check and goes straight to ``save()``? If so, you might want to break your ``if``s out into separate functions that return true or false for the condition check, then call them with ``if (condition1() || condition2()...) save()`` or something along those lines. If it's literally just "try them all and remember if at least one condition was met" then a flag is ideal!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any clever way to do it concisely in Kotlin, but in most cases I would probably prefer assigning conditions to variables over the `flag` approach:

```kotlin
val isBlue = ... some condition ...
val hasWings = ... another condition ...

if (isBlue) {
   ...
}
if (hasWings) {
   ...
}
if (isBlue || hasWings) {
   ...
}
```

Of course, it is a matter of personal taste.

Also, in some cases `flag` makes more sense. There is `save()` in your example, so if this flag is something like `shouldSaveData` and it depends on several conditions where for example the data is mutated, then `flag` approach makes perfect sense.